# Get workspace details in podio api

Tags: podio

Is there any way to get work space name and URL if the API request is authenticated as app.

```
Podio::authenticate_with_app($app_id, $app_token);
PodioSpace::get($space_id);
```

the above code return PodioForbiddenError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but the I don't think this is allowed within the scope hierarchy.
Please refer to https://developers.podio.com/authentication/scopes

---

But, if you only need space name, id, url and couple of other minor details you could still get it by using `fields` parameter. This is described here: https://developers.podio.com/index/api (scroll down to the end of page).

Here is how I debug it with **Ruby**:

```
  Podio.client.authenticate_with_app(<app_id>, <app_token>)
  app = Podio::Application.find(app_id, {'fields' => 'space.view(full)'})
  puts app['space']['name']
  puts app['space']['space_id']
  puts app['space']['url']
```